# React Navigation, cannot find navigation when trying to go back

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a function to the `headerLeft`, however I cannot find navigation in my props. How can I go back in my `headerLeft` component?

```
pakage.json:

    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/core": "5.16.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "5.12.9",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "5.3.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.9",



const sharedHeaderOptions: StackNavigationOptions = {
  headerShown: true,
  headerTitleStyle,
  headerTitleAlign: 'left',
  headerTitleContainerStyle,
  headerLeftContainerStyle: headingStyles?.headerLeftContainerStyle,
  headerLeft: () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        console.log('go back');
        navigation.goBack();
      }}>
      <BackChevron />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
  headerBackImage: () => {},
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerTintColor: colors.INACTIVE_THUMBCOLOR,
};

const FuelFinderStackScreen = () => (
  <FuelFinderStack.Navigator initialRouteName={AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearch.Name}>
    <FuelFinderStack.Screen
      name={AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearch.Name}
      component={SearchScreen}
      options={{
        ...sharedHeaderOptions,
        headerTitle: fuelFinderMappings.search.screenTitle,
      }}
    />
    <FuelFinderStack.Screen
      name={AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearchResults.Name}
      component={SearchResultListScreen}
      options={sharedHeaderOptions}
    />
  </FuelFinderStack.Navigator>
);

export default FuelFinderStackScreen;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first question is where you expected the navigation object to come from?
I'm assuming that you are using `react-navigation` v6 so this will probably fix the issue:

1. Change your `sharedHeaderOptions` to a function receiving the navigation object or the stack props.
2. The parameter `option` from the stack screen can expose the object `navigation` thru the usage of a param. So you could probably change it to:

```
const getSharedHeaderOptions: (navigation: {
        route: RouteProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
        navigation: any;
      }) => StackNavigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  headerShown: true,
  headerTitleStyle,
  headerTitleAlign: 'left',
  headerTitleContainerStyle,
  headerLeftContainerStyle: headingStyles?.headerLeftContainerStyle,
  headerLeft: () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        console.log('go back');
        navigation.goBack(); //now this solve issue 1, you get the object from the param
      }}>
      <BackChevron />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
  headerBackImage: () => {},
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerTintColor: colors.INACTIVE_THUMBCOLOR,
});

const FuelFinderStackScreen = () => (
  <FuelFinderStack.Navigator initialRouteName={AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearch.Name}>
    <FuelFinderStack.Screen
      name={AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearch.Name}
      component={SearchScreen}
      options={getSharedHeaderOptions}
    />
    <FuelFinderStack.Screen
      name={AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearchResults.Name}
      component={SearchResultListScreen}
      options={getSharedHeaderOptions}
    />
  </FuelFinderStack.Navigator>
);

export default FuelFinderStackScreen;
```

Take into consideration that `options` have the following type:

```
options?: ScreenOptions
    | ((props: {
        route: RouteProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
        navigation: any;
      }) => ScreenOptions);
```

Comment: I'm using version 5, would your fixes still apply?

Comment: @Bomber yes, give it a try. Options expose the same param object. I'm not certainly sure if the type is exactly the same but it should work for your needs.